# Zipping files with relative path?

Tags: bash, macos, path, zip

I'm trying to create backups of my USB key. For that, I'd need to zip the content of my USB key (`/Volumes/<USB KEY NAME>/`). I have this code for the moment
`zip -r /Volumes/<USB KEY NAME>/*`
That seems to work, except the fact that when I extract my archive, I get :

(For simplfication purpose (and laziness), `<USB KEY NAME>+(<DATE>).zip` is `Archive.zip`)

```
Archive.zip
    -> Volumes
        -> <USB KEY NAME>
            -> <USB KEY CONTENT>
                -> ...
```

How to get just :

```
Archive.zip
    -> <USB KEY NAME>
        -> <USB KEY CONTENT>
            -> ...
```

I know it's something about absolute/relative paths but that's all I know. How could I do this ?

PS : I'm on MacOS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the `-j` option.

It stores just the name of the saved files (junk the path), and does not store directory names. By default, `zip` will store the full path (relative to the current path).

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error, saying that I have to files with the same name, and that it is propably because I have the -j option, so what can I do?

Comment: Try changing your working directory into the USB drive prior to zipping your files. Include the original -r option but not the -j option.

So: cd /Volumes/<USB KEY NAME>/ then
zip -r *

Answer (score 6):

As `man zip` tell us,

> -j
> --junk-paths
> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. **By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory)**.

However, **`-j` will discard all path information**, which caused all files be put in same package without any path information.

**Method 1**:
Change current directory(`cd`)

```bash
cd /Volumes; zip -rq $(OLDPWD)/Archive.zip <USB_Key_Name>; cd -
```

**Method 2**:
Symlink will help

```bash
ln -s /Volumes/<USB_Key_Name> . # create symlink to avoid cd
zip -rq Archive.zip <USB_Key_Name>
rm <USB_Key_Name> # remove symlink
```

Answer (score 0):

just control path to the target archive

```
cd /Volumes/<USB KEY NAME>;
zip -r ../../archive.zip *

  adding: ./file-in-usb-key-name-dir (stored 0%)
  adding: ./subdir/file (stored 0%)
  ...
```